# How to dynamically switch a `ggroup` from `horizontal=TRUE` to `horizontal=FALSE`?

Tags: r, containers, gwidgets

How could I change a `ggroup` from `horizontal=TRUE` to `horizontal=FALSE` in a gWidgets2 GUI that is already visible? Consider the following:

```
w <- gwindow("Box containers")
g <- ggroup(horizontal=TRUE, cont=w)
gbutton("one", cont=g); gbutton("two", cont=g)
```

If I now execute:

```
g <- ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, cont=w)
```

then the GUI blanks out. Instead, I would have expected the `g` container to become `horizontal=FALSE` and for the contained buttons to be vertically arranged. How can the latter be achieved?

Comment: It isn't so easy. In `Qt` the underlying widget allows this behaviour, but as far as I know, not `Gtk`. If you really wanted to do this, you could reparent, but it would be tricky.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by "reparent"? Put `g` into another `ggroup` object? It would be great if you could give an example of this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not work cross platform, but with Gtk it does:

```
w = gwindow()
g = ggroup(cont=w)
g1 = ggroup(cont=g)
g2 = ggroup(cont=g, horizontal=FALSE)
b1 = gbutton("asdf", cont=g1)
b2 = gbutton("asdfadfasd", cont=g1)
## reparent by deleting, then adding:
delete(g1, b1)
delete(g1, b2)
add(g2, b1)
add(g2, b2)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. In fact I found a seemingly more elegant solution, which I posted as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach similar to the accepted answer is to `add`/`delete` the container itself, and not the buttons:

```
w = gwindow()
g = ggroup(cont=w)
g1 = ggroup(cont=g)
b1 = gbutton("asdf", cont=g1)
b2 = gbutton("asdfadfasd", cont=g1)
g2 = ggroup(cont=g, horizontal=FALSE)
b1bis = gbutton("asdf", cont=g2)
b2bis = gbutton("asdfadfasd", cont=g2)
delete(g, g2)
## reparent by deleting, then adding:
delete(g, g1)
add(g, g2)
## switch back to original layout
delete(g, g2)
add(g, g1)
```

Comment: You should also look at `gstackwidget` for this kind of manipulation. The advantage of the other solution is you don't need to reset any signal handlers. You can also iterate over the `children` property of the container to do the deletion/insertion via `sapply`. The `gstackwidget` style or your style will work with `gWidgets2tcltk`, the other won't.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I'm not very familiar with `gstackwidget`. Would you consider adding an example using this approach?

Comment: It is easy: replace your `g` with `g = gstackwidget(cont=w)`. Then instead of deleting g1 or g2 you just switch via `svalue(g) <- 1` (or `2`). This is similar to `gnotebook` but without the visual tabs.